Jetpack Compose LazyVerticalGrid causes IllegalStateException when added to LinearLayout without max height
I’m working with a LinearLayout as a parent layout in my Android app. Based on different card types, I dynamically add various cards to the LinearLayout. One of these cards is built using Jetpack Compose, where I use the LazyVerticalGrid component.
When I don’t specify a max height for LazyVerticalGrid, the app crashes with the following error:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Vertically scrollable component was measured with an infinity maximum height constraints, which is disallowed.
If I set a fixed height (e.g. 400.dp), the layout works, but I want it to adjust dynamically based on content without hardcoding the height.
What I’ve Tried:
•Wrapping LazyVerticalGrid in Box or Column with Modifier.fillMaxHeight(), but it still crashes without a max height.
•Works with a fixed height like 400.dp, but I need it to adjust dynamically.
Key Code Snippet :
    cells = GridCells.Fixed(2),
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .heightIn(max = 400.dp) // Works with fixed height
) {
    items(100) {
        Text("Item $it")
    }
}

The Question:
How can I make LazyVerticalGrid work without a fixed height in LinearLayout? Is there a way for it to adjust dynamically based on content?

Are you placing the LazyVerticalGrid inside another scrollable layout? If so, it could be causing conflicting height constraints. Could you provide more details about the parent layout structure?

ParentLayout is linearlayout in activity, Inside that linearlayout I am adding composeview dynamically. In that compose I am using LazyVerticalGrid which is causing issue of height.

I'm just guessing that one of parent GroupView is scrollable which is causing the crash issue. Can you provide more detail about your XML file, maybe it's more useful so I could help ^^



No for NestedScrollView also it's same issue.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/compose/lists#avoid-nesting-scrollable I think you should try other approaches

You mentioned that you have a structure like
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <Card/>
        <ComposeView/>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

You can't use a Composable with fillMaxHeight within another scrollable container (like ScrollView). The reason is that a vertically scrolling container only is as high as its content. There is no specific height for the vertically scrolling container, thus, there is no maximum available height that a child Composable could fill.
I would suggest that you reconsider your actual requirement, because usually, when people stumble across this issue, they actually have a UI design problem:

If the Card containing the LazyVerticalGrid was as big as the phone screen, then the user couldn't continue scrolling down the Card list once they reach at the LazyVerticalGrid. Then, all scroll inputs would be consumed by the LazyVerticalGrid. The user would have to scroll through the whole LazyVerticalGrid before being able to scroll further down in the Card list. This is a bad user experience.
Alternatively, you can make the Card as big as all content displayed inside the LazyVerticalGrid. However, you then would need to replace LazyVerticalGrid with a combination of Row and Column, as with lazy Composables, we never know how long the content actually is. Also, you might be ending up with a very long Card, which also isn't a good user experience.

So naturally, the only way to provide an acceptable user experience is if you give the Card a certain fixed height. If the user wants to inspect all the contents, they can scroll the Card, or even better, open a detail page with the full LazyVerticalGrid. If they are not interested into the Card, they have enough screen area left to scroll the ScrollView instead of scrolling the LazyVerticalGrid.
However, you should generally avoid having two components scrolling into the same direction nested under each other.

Increase the height value
heightIn(max = 4000.dp)


This I have tried but it's having some scroll related issue.
